# wait for process to exit when using CreateProcessAsUser

Tags: c#

i'm using **CreateProcessAsUser** in c# to launch a process by a service
my service needs to waiting for the process to exit but i don't know how i can do it,
i don't want to use checking the process existion in processes list

Comment: I added an example of how the process handle can be wrapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://www.pinvoke.net/ for signatures. Here's a sime example.

```
 const UInt32 INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;

 // Declare variables
 PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
 STARTUPINFO si;
 System.IntPtr hToken;

 // Create structs
 SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saThreadAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();    

 // Now create the process as the user
 if (!CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, String.Empty, commandLine,
 null, saThreadAttributes, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, si, pi))
 {
 // Throw exception
 throw new Exception("Failed to CreateProcessAsUser");
 }

 WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, (int)INFINITE);
```

Answer (score 8):

The [PROCESS_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684873(v=VS.85).aspx) returns the handle to the newly created process (`hProcess`), you can wait on this handle which will become signaled when the process exits.

You can use [SafeWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safewaithandle.aspx) encapsulate the handle and then use [WaitHandle.WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=VS.100).aspx) to wait for the process to exit.

Here is how you would wrap the process handle

```
class ProcessWaitHandle : WaitHandle
{
  public ProcessWaitHandle(IntPtr processHandle)
  {
    this.SafeWaitHandle = new SafeWaitHandle(processHandle, false);
  }
}
```

And then the following code can wait on the handle

```
ProcessWaitHandle waitable = new ProcessWaitHandle(pi.hProcess);
waitable.WaitOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GetExitCodeProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189(VS.85).aspx), but note that this function returns immediately.

Another approach is using [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032(VS.85).aspx). But this requires the process to be opened with the [SYNCHRONIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880(v=VS.85).aspx) flag. Example:

```
IntPtr hwnd = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, 0, pid);
if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero) {
    WaitForSingleObject(hwnd, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hwnd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CreateProcessAsUser` returns you a structure `PROCESS_INFORMATION`, which contains `hProcess` - process handle. This is a valid handle for `WaitForSingleObject`/`WaitForMultipleObjects` functions.

MSDN: [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28VS.85%29.aspx), [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28VS.85%29.aspx)