# How to wait for CreateProcessAsUser to complete in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I am using following function to launch a particular exe. I need to wait for this process to complete before moving onto next set of code. How do i wait for the process to complete?

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
extern static Boolean CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, Boolean bInheritHandle, Int32 dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        String lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
```

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2980423/7270462

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct you get back from the method also contains the handle of the created process and its ID. So you could for example do this:

```
Process.GetProcessById(procInfo.dwProcessId).WaitForExit()
```

However, note that if the process terminates before you get to this call, it could be remotely possible you'd get a different process instead. So it would be better to do some validation, just in case:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessById(procInfo.dwProcessId);

if (process.Handle == procInfo.hProcess)
  process.WaitForExit();

// The process has definitely exited by now
```

However, you don't have to use `CreateProcessAsUser` at all. You can use a `Process.Start` overload that allows you to specify username and password - this should be the preferred way to start a process under a diferent user in C#. You can also use `ProcessStartInfo` to specify a username and password.